# ¿Error al consumir un servicio web api desde angular $http.post?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

El error es el siguiente 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi mètodo POST en el Web Api

```
// POST api/values
[HttpPost]
public string Post(Persona persona)
{
     return "response: \"Suscrito\"";
}
```

y este es mi còdigo angular.

```
    $http.post('http://localhost:54969/api/values',
                $scope.persona).success(function (result) {
        alert('Success!');
    }).error(function (data) {
        alert("Error!");
    });
```

no entiendo el error y no me queda claro si el error lo tengo en el servicio o en el angular.

Por favor alguien me ayuda!

Comment: Hola. Te recomiendo que leas esto: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api , sobre todo si estás construyendo un servicio que imagino, estará disponible para ser consultado. He visto respuestas diciendo que configures tu Web App de forma que reciba peticiones de cualquier origen. Esto no es siempre lo ideal. Nota: para futuras preguntas es mejor poner texto y no imágenes, es más útil y las imágenes se ven con dificultad en dispositivos pequeños.

Answer (score 0):

Nunca usé asp pero puedes intentar una de las soluciones que hay [aquí](http://sibeeshpassion.com/fix-to-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-or-working-with-cross-origin-request-in-asp-net-web-api/) que es agregar lo siguiente al fichero `Web.config`

```
 <system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias testear tu webservice mandando el parametro por Post y ver si ahi da el error.

Con angularjs lo arias de esta forma

```
$scope.CrearUsuario = function(item)
        {
            $scope.item = item;
            $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:808/sistemadrp/public/ws/usuarios",
                data: {
                    usuario:    item.usuario,
                    nombre:     item.nombre,
                    email:      item.email,
                    password:   item.password,
                    telefono:   item.telefono,
                    estado:     item.estado
                }
            }).then(function mySucess(response)
            {
                modalCrear.hide();
                UIkit.notify({
                                message : 'Registro creado exitosamente!',
                                status  : 'success',
                                timeout :  5000,
                                pos     : 'top-right'
                            });
               $window.location.reload();
            },function myError(response){
                console.log("Error");
            });
        }
```

el parametro item lo utilizo en el formulario `ng-model="item.nombre1"`

Answer (score 0):

EL problema viene porque estás intentando hacer una llamada ajax a un dominio distinto al que está sirviendo el front. Desde el backend tienes que indicarle que "aceptas" llamadas desde el dominio del front (o habilitar cualquier dominio con `*`, útil para api's publicas). Para ello debes responder a las solicitudes con los siguientes headers (para que el navegador acepte las respuestas).

```
  // Headers para habilitar el acceso a tu front (En el caso que propones)
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "localhost:53100"
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
// Habilitar el acceso desde cualquier dominio
   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"
   "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
```

En ASP.NET no te puedo echar una mano a nivel de codigo, pero aquí tienes un enalce que puede servirte https://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html

Esto se conoce como **CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)**. Si buscan en google *enable CORS in ASP.NET* seguro encuentras mucho enlaces que te servirán de ayuda.

Espero haber despejado un poco más tus dudas!